# Issue Getting "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, database-connection

I an working on window application and i have one method for checking the connection is open if open then closed and i have a single instance of connection object but i am getting the issue "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."
Here is my code:

```
public static SqlConnection connection { get; set; }

    public static SqlConnection GetOpenConnnection()
    {
        string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();
        if (connection == null)
            connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();
       return connection;

    }
```

Please tell me why i am getting this issue, if i create connection object every time then its working. so please tell me cant i have one connection object for whole application.

Comment: You should create a connection object every time you need it and destroy it when the particular task has completed. Do not keep a global connection  for the lifetime of your application. The [Connection Pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) infrastructure removes the performance penalty required to re-create the connection

Comment: And for your problem. Make the property private and force every point of your code to pass through the static GetOpenConnection. I think that somewhere you set the public property and forget to set the connectionstring.

Comment: yes actually i did a mistake i return this connection in using statement so at the end of using connection get disposed i think and here i have check if connection is not null then only create new connection. so i am trying to open disposed connection. I think this is the issue. i checked it by removing the using block and its working.

Comment: Still, you shouldn't use a global connection object. Using exists for a reason

Comment: @Steve, but if i have global connection  object and its close only not dispose then it will create performance issue? i can again open that connection when i have need. please tell me this too.. Thank you.

Comment: And what is the point to Close a global connection and keep around an unusable global variable?. You need to check and reopen it (everytime) and the unwanted bug is there waiting to hit you. If you want to avoid the call to new remember that, in NET, instancing an object is (usually) a very light operation.